# How to remove a widget from the home screen on Oreo

Tags: app-widgets

I used the  Widgets app (press and hold on the home screen) to install the calendar schedule widget. I no longer want it displayed. There must be a simple way of removing it, but I can't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a widgets by long clicking on it and dragging it to the top of the screen where a text is saying remove.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks very much. I had been trying to press on the "X Remove" text after the widget was selected.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept my answer if it worked.